# RShiny: Trying to centre my leaflet but I want the legend to stay left justified

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, leaflet

I've searched around google and stack overflow but haven't found this question asked before.
Basically I want to centre my leafletOutput and have done so with this code:

```
UI <-fluidPage(
fluidRow(width=12, align="center",
(leafletOutput("Map2", width=1450, height=700)))
)
```

Except then it centres my legend which makes it look really weird.
So I want to centre the plot but keep the legend in the bottom right corner (which it is) but with the text left aligned (it is being center aligned).

I've also tried this:

```
fluidRow(width=12, align="center",
(leafletOutput("Map2", width=1450, height=700, div(style="text-align: left;")))
```

However this left aligns the entire image, basically over-riding the align="center" in the fluidRow.

I've also tried running this in the server:

```
addLegend(div(style="text-align: left;"), pal=pal,values =~MerchCoOrds$merchant_state, opacity=1, title="State of Transaction",
position="bottomright")
```

But the text stays center aligned.

This is my current server code:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
output$Map2 <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet(MerchCoOrds) %>% addTiles() %>%
      addCircleMarkers(data=MerchCoOrds, lng=~MerchLongitude, lat=~MerchLatitude, col = ~pal(MerchCoOrds$merchant_state), 
                       stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 1.0, 
                       popup=~paste("<h3>Merchant ID:</h3>",MerchCoOrds$merchant_id, "<h3>Transaction ID:</h3>", 
                                    MerchCoOrds$transaction_id, sep=" "), 
                       label=labels) %>%
      addLegend(pal=pal,values =~MerchCoOrds$merchant_state, opacity=1, title="State of Transaction",
                position="bottomright") %>%
      addControl(title, position="topright")
    })
}
```

I'm sure there's a way using tags or div but I'm brand new to R and especially to Shiny.
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UI <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(width=12, align="center",
        leafletOutput("Map2", width=1450, height=700),
        tags$style(HTML("#Map2 .info {text-align:left;}"))
    )
)
```

I had the same issue with the tooltip text as it has several rows and managed to get it left aligned with:

```
tags$style(HTML("#NameOfLeafletOutput .leaflet-tooltip {text-align:left;}")),
```

while my Leaflet map stays centred.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was able to fix it using this simple code tweak in the UI.
I changed the `fluidRow` to an `absolutePanel` and removed the `align="centre"` and added in `left = "12%"`

```
absolutePanel(left = "12%", width=12, 
      (leafletOutput("Map2", width=1450, height=700))
```

There must be a better more sustainable solution I'm sure, so if anyone has a better solution please post it, as this is more of a work around than a solution.

Thanks